# Publishing to Azure workaround: trying to understand compiled files to upload them by FTP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, .net-core

We have not been able to publish to Azure from Visual Studio (for Windows). We managed to do it with Visual Studio for Mac, but we just did not find the way in Windows. Publish seems to work with zero errors, but nothing seems to be pushed in reality. We have also realised we have created another App Service / Server somehow from Visual Studio, so maybe we are pushing to the wrong place not sure why or how to fix it.

Anyway, we have found a way to access to the published files within Visual Studio (by FTP, I guess):

[image: compiled files uploaded to Azure]

We have updated files that don't need to be compiled (which sometimes does not seem to work either, by the way. Maybe because we are uploading to the wrong server? Maybe some cache stuff?).

Anyway, **my question is about how to upload compiled files manually, I mean, by FTP:**

- May we just upload a full local folder with the compiled files to Azure?
- Or maybe compiled files in local environment are different than compiled files to upload to Azure?

Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @IvanYang my mate did not try it yet. He hates Azure now xD

Comment: ah, when I begin using azure, yeah, I hated it :(. But when use it more and more, now don't hate it so much :).

Answer (score 0):

For compiled files, like they are all in the `bin` folder of your project, you need to upload the `bin` folder to azure via ftp.

I can confirm this behavior by using visual studio FTP deploy azure web app.